# Length contraction from a contracted frame of reference (thought experiment)

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers, thought-experiment

Consider the following situation:

[image]

You are moving with high speed on a road on earth and are looking at the night sky, in particular at two stars.

In the rest frame of earth, you and your eye are length contracted. This implies that the proper distance between the images of the stars on your retina is greater than the distance between the images on the retina of an observer at rest w.r.t. the earth (in my calculations the angles also change, but this does not influence the distance, because both angles change).

But because the position of the dots on your retina (or more specifically, the cells that are excited by starlight) are independent of the frame of reference, you also observe a distance between the two stars that is greater than the other observer.
Now that is a problem, because special relativity says you should observe a smaller distance (the sky is length contracted).

So the question is did I make a mistake? Is this actually what happens?

Comment: Can close voters please leave a comment. I don't see why this question should be closed, OP clearly put thought into it. This is not a "homework-style question" as one of the close voters gave as a reason... OP is new and if there is anything to improve with his question, please comment to help him.

Comment: One problem is "perspective". Rather, discuss 2 frames: $S$ and $S'$. Also: how does a spot on a retina affect anything about the stars' separation?

Comment: @phlipp can you please explain why you think the length contracted distance between the two spots on the retina implies to the outside observer that the person in the car sees the stars as further apart.

Comment: @JEB I rewrote the question a bit. It's not about the stars' actual separation but about the images on the retina, which in some circumstances will be farther apart (in proper distance) in the boosted frame.

Comment: @MarcoOcram The argument is that the coordinate separation in the lab frame of the star images on the retina should be independent of the speed of the eye, which is true if the retina is flat and the stars are symmetrically positioned in the lab frame. That implies the proper separation on the moving retina is larger. I rewrote the question a bit.

Comment: @doublefelix :  I agree that the question requires some thought and the OP clearly thought about it.   But why does that make it "non-homework-like"?   Nearly every homework problem I've ever assigned has required some thought.

Comment: @WillO OP is asking conceptual questions rather than for us to calculate for him. Sure that could have been inspired by a homework, but at that point just about any question could be classified as homework.

Answer (score 1):

You are not making a mistake, except in thinking that this is a problem. As always, the key to solving this dilemma is the relativity of simultaneity.

For simplicity consider the following geometry: in the earth frame the distant stars are at rest and are at equal and opposite angles from the vertical along the direction of travel for the car. At that moment the rider in the car receives a momentary flicker in the light from each star.

In the earth frame those flickers occurred simultaneously, and so the optical separation of the light sources is equal to the distance between the stars.

In the car frame, however, those two flickers occurred at different times. This means that the optical separation is not equal to the distance in this frame. Between the times of the two flickers the stars have moved such that the optical separation is greater than the distance between the stars in the car frame.

Answer (score 0):

This might not directly answer your question, but I want to remind you that "length contraction" might not mean that "in your view, the length is contracted" since the lights from the objects need time to propagate to your eyes.

Here is a video trying to simulate the visual effect of special relativity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQnHTKZBTI4. You can see that the object might not be actually "contracted" in your view. Here is another video explaining the reason behind the optical effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l44JSW-1RvE.

Hope this answer clarifies some part of your question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> *You are moving with high speed on a road on earth and are looking at the night sky, in particular at two stars.*

From a somewhat practical point of view, even the speed of any (section of) road itself, on Earth's surface, with respect to a non-rotating quasi-inertial frame which is momentarily comoving with Earth's center) [is comparatively high](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed#Tangential_velocities_at_altitude) compared to typical speeds of cars "going really fast" wrt. the road surface (except for road section in "high polar regions" of Earth);
and even more so the speed, namely [roughly 30 km/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed#Planets) of any (section of) road on Earth's surface wrt. the non-rotating quasi-inertial frame which is comoving wrt. the center of the Sun.

> *[...] But because the position of the dots on your retina (or more specifically, the cells that are excited by starlight)*

... it is certainly correct and useful to be just as specific about the concrete identifiable constituents (a.k.a. participants) of the setup under consideration ...

> *are independent of the frame of reference,*

That's (bordering on being) incorrect, and consequential misleading.
Recall W. Rindler's dictum that

["*An inertial frame is simply an infinite set of point particles sitting still in space relative to each other*"](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Special_relativity:_kinematics).

In this sense, the set of starlight-collecting cells in (or rather, making up) the retina of the driver you described **constitutes itself a** (small, or at least partial) **particular frame of reference**.

> *you also observe a distance between the two stars that is greater than the other observer.*

That's (bordering on being) incorrect. No: distances or not ("plainly") observed, but distances, or more specifically: ratios of distances, **are measured** (in ideal cases, including thought experiments); or, in more practical circumstances, distance ratios are estimated (usually accompanied by a quantitative stateent, or at least a qualitative discussion, about the range of confidence of the estimate).

This is especially relevant when understanding "length contraction" as referring to the measured distance ratio between certain pairs of participants who belong to different (inertial) reference frames which move (uniformly) wrt. each other;
in [Einstein's popular example](https://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/5001/pg5001-images.html#ch10) specifically the distance ratio between

- the distance (A'B') of two specific identifiably constituents, A' and B', of a train (which moves with some speed v on a railway embankment) and
- the distance (AB) of two specific identifiably constituents, A and B, of the railway embankment, which are identified (in rlation to train constituents A' and B') by the requirement that the (clock) indication of A at the passage of A' **is simultaneous to** the (clock) indication of B at the passage of B'.

It can be shown and has been shown that this specific distance ratio, (A'B') / (AB), has the value $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2}}$; cmp. for instance eq. $(1\rm d)$ in [this derivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/686765/12262).