# Special Relativity Problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity

If a spacecraft start moving away from the earth, spacecraft has crtain velocity according to earth. But the earth has this velocity according to spacecraft. Now whose time will increase according to whom and why?

Comment: Each measures the other's clock to be running slow. Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/383248/123208

Comment: Thanks man. That was useful