# Question about Time Dilation

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

I was studying about Time dilation and I wondered, does Time seem less for a moving body, or does it seem less for a resting body, both relative to each other, or does both occur at same time?
Meaning if moving body experience 1s, does resting body experience lets say 0.5s?
Or is it the other way around?
Or does both happen?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [How can time dilation be symmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/383248/how-can-time-dilation-be-symmetric)

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, it is the principle of relativity that each observer views nature as if he is stationary with all the other observers moving. Once people recover from the initial shock of time dilation, this is usually where they get tripped up. They think in terms of "A sees B with time slowed down, so B sees A with time sped up" or something like that. This is not correct. The time dilation is [reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Reciprocity).

FWIW, if you are serious about learning this and not just asking a random question, I always recommend people move on past "time dilation" and "[length contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction)" as soon as they are able and think in terms of [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) and the [Lorentz transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation). While the math may seem harder, this is because it is more accurate. The "paradoxes" will all be much easier to resolve.

It is OK if you were just asking and are not intending on deep study too, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looking forward to studying about Minkowski Space and Lorentz Transformation

Comment: Time dilation and length contraction are just particular applications of the Lorentz transformation, which is the general way to settle how two different observers view the same event in special relativity.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a good video/ way/ site to learn the Lorentz Transformation?           Actually I'm not using any kind of book since neither an I in any course not do I have such a book.

Comment: Do you have a gen phys book? Are you in high school or college or something?

Comment: No I'm in class 11th and my general physics book doesn't mention anything about relativity. Its only school level

Comment: Although i do think I can find the Feynman Lectures on Physics Vol 1

Comment: You can find lectures online (MIT and the like). If you are an 11th grade high school student who has only used an elementary intro book, I would try an ordinary undergrad gen phys book. Also, there are a variety of "learning physics" books, like the Feynman lectures as you said. Feynman's Six Easy Pieces and Six Not So Easy Pieces are a good subset of that too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @RudranshJoshi :  If you are comfortable sharing an email address, I can send you some notes that I think you'll find helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this answer is correct in theory, it is not correct in the real world.  In the real world there is a preferred frame of reference so that the traveling clock will never see the stationary clock as ticking faster, but not for any of the reasons mentioned above or in the wiki article.  I have provided a complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Moving bodies experience less time in their reference frame compared to bodies at rest. This is what special relativity says , so for a given speed the moving body experiences 0.5 s where as the body at rest experiences 1s. If we increase the speed to speed of light then actually the body doesn't have a defined amount of time ( hence light doesn't experience time) because in the time dilation equation we usually compare the speeds to speed of light
$$t^{'} = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$
t' is the new time experienced by the moving body c is the speed of light v is the velocity of body t is the time at rest . here $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$
is known as the lorentz factor .

here as v is divided by c , so as speed increases the value of denominator  also decreases and so the value of t' increases having more magnitude of time consumed so  hence time experienced by the moving body is less!

Comment: The Lorentz Factor will take a value always greater than or equal to 1. Wouldn't that mean that t is smaller than t'?

Comment: Rudransh, yes, this is why I recommend people do it the real way if they are serious. One t will be bigger than the other depending upon the event under consideration. The smallest possible t is called the "proper time" (the rest are dilated) much like the largest possible length is the "proper length" (the rest are contracted). Which is which is a source of errors and other than the simplest of "popular demonstrations" should just be done with the formal transformation in my opinion.

Comment: You mean the Lorentz Transformation? Will do it surely for my own sake

Comment: @RudranshJoshi yes I had done a mistake at the last part now I edited it  thank you

Comment: @NaveenV Ok thanks

Comment: "Moving bodies experience less time relative to bodies at rest." Your use of the word "experience" is misleading here. None of the bodies experiences anything different than the others in their own reference frame - only as judged from the other frame.

Comment: That's what I tried to tell , thanks for letting me know my choice of words is misleading @D.Halsey

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is where you say

> Meaning if moving body experience 1s, does resting body experience lets say 0.5s?

The reason this is problematic is because, when you have two bodies that are not always in the same place, it is not clear how you are supposed to be comparing the time each one experiences. From a pre-relativistic perspective, this may seem confusing, as Newtonian physics admits a unique global time coordinate, allowing us to introduce a notion of "simultaneity" for this purpose. However, this is not the case in Einsteinian Relativity. Instead, if we want to compare the amount of time each body experiences, we must specify how the two bodies are communicating with each other (such as by sending each other light signals or by starting and ending in the same place), so that we can calculate the [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) of each path.

---

Note, some people like to talk about the notion of [relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity) in Special Relativity, in which there is a reference frame-dependent notion of simultaneity. However, I prefer not to think of things this way, since it does not naturally extend to General Relativity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, the common perception of reciprocal time dilation is simply wrong. And it has nothing to do with acceleration, or turning around, or anything like that.  The fact is that there IS a preferred frame of reference and this is proven every day with GPS satellites.  Allow me to explain:

As you know, GPS satellites have their clocks adjusted for both special and general relativistic effects.  So clocks on a GPS satellite run 45 microseconds per day faster than clocks on the ground. If this was not done then we would quickly drive off the road.

Other satellites (and intercontinental ballistic missiles) use GPS satellites to set their own navigation.  Some of these satellites are following right behind the GPS satellite orbit, so they have no relative motion compared the GPS satellite. While other satellites are going in the exact opposite orbit, so they have extremely fast relative motion compared the GPS satellite.  And others still are traveling at various cross angles to the GPS orbit, so they would have various relative motions.

If the concepts of special relativity were correct, then all of these other satellites would need to set their clocks and motion relative to the GPS satellite.  But they DO NOT do this.  They all set their clocks and motion relative to Earth. It is only in this way that the missiles reach their correct target.

Second, the wikipedia page referred to in another answer on [reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Reciprocity) says that the reason the twin paradox is resolved is because the travelling twin must accelerate and turn around.  This is also wrong. Lets imagine not twins, but quintuplets.  Ann stays on Earth, Bob travels to star Beta and back; Charles to star Gama and back, Doris to Delta and back, Evelyn to star Epsilon  and back.  All of the travelling quints use exactly the same acceleration rate up to a top speed of .8c.  They all turn around their star in exactly the same circle and they all decelerate at the same rate on return to Earth.  The wiki article would imply that all the traveling quints age the same amount compared to Ann, because they all followed the same acceleration patterns. But this is not the case.  The acceleration has absolutely nothing to do with this special relativistic effect.  The only issue is how much time (or distance) they travelled at what speed.  At the end of the experiment Ann will be oldest, Bob will be second oldest, Charles third oldest, Doris fourth oldest and Evelyn will be youngest.

These facts lead us to understand that while in theory there is no preferred frame of reference, in the real world there IS a preferred frame of reference.

Comment: I have heard of this GPS / missile argument but have not been convinced (I know it is very controversial here, and I am not going to down vote or start yelling, but I'm not convinced). As you say, GPS drifts at about 45 microseconds per day. I fail to see why this would matter during the short flight of a missile. Missiles that stay up for several days would eventually see the same drift, but then those would not be missiles, those would be other satellites. It seems entirely conceivable to me that ICBMs going in different directions see different time drifts, yet still hit their targets.

Comment: @PoissonAerohead  Think more about other satellites that are following behind or in the opposite orbit as the GPS satellites.  The difference here would be massive.

Comment: In physics we don't just say things like "the difference would be massive." We say things that are quantified. So my point stands, the claimed physics of the GPS system are public knowledge as is the "mainstream" version of relativity. If people claim ICBMs using GPS is inconsistent with relativity, then they should quantify that based on the math of relativity. In physics, that is how you demonstrate a theory to be wrong. No one disputes that during the flight ICBMs will see different time dilations than ground observers do and it varies by direction, they dispute it precludes them using GPS.

Comment: @PoissonAerohead Here you go, all the math you would ever want:  https://www.naturalphilosophy.org/pdf/abstracts/abstracts_1785.pdf

Comment: I have been meaning to look at this paper, thanks, but just scanning it quickly I still don't see where he quantifies what *should* be seen and compares it to what *actually is*. Further, regarding your "quintuplet" example (honestly triplets is enough), again, what is actually predicted by the theory and what is actually observed? Relativity happened because the MM experiment contradicted certain predictions. If you can do a "traveling triplet paradox" experiment that contradicts relativity, we would all want to see it. All you offer is the sentence "But this is not the case." What is then?

Comment: @PoissonAerohead  The trouble with MM is that they only used light. Real objects (like rockets or quintuplets) contain things like quarks and gluons that react with real quantum fields other than the electromagnetic field.   I'm sure that MM is right if we are only looking at spacetime.  But once we add quantum fields on top of spacetime, the thinking must change.  You can find my entire speculative theory "dilating loop relativity" here: https://zenodo.org/record/7591244#.Y_0kal7MLq5   All of this is explained in as much detail as I can manage.

Comment: Sure. I'll let you know that while I have not done it (or seen it elsewhere), my suspicion is that the flight of an ICBM using a properly calibrated GPS network (it needs daily calibration of course) can be explained with no problems relativistically. If that is not true, then so be it. However, I have yet to see anyone who makes these claims properly set up a system and actually analyze the flight of the missile and what the men at the launch sight see as it flies, I only see hand waving that "clearly it would not be able to navigate" or whatever. It is not "clear" to me at all.