# Why doesn't Galilean relativity lead to a contradiction in SR?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, time-dilation, galilean-relativity

Two identical spaceships commanded by Alice and Bob are at rest next to each other in outer space.  The clocks of the spaceships are synchronised; and when they are close by Alice can see Bob's clock and vice versa. Both spaceships then accelerate away from each other in opposite directions.  After a while both spaceships slow down, stop, turn round and return to their starting position passing each other at constant high velocity. The equations of motion of the two spaceships are identical, save for the fact that they went in opposite directions--in Cartesian coordinates you can replace x by -x.

As they pass each other at constant velocity Alice and Bob note the time on their own clock and the clock of the other spaceship.  Alice looks at her clock; it says noon.  She looks at Bob's clock; it says 11.55am.  Alice knows about special relativity. In her inertial frame she is at rest. Bob is moving. She knows moving clocks run slow, and is not surprised that Bob's says 11.55am.

Bob looks at his own clock; it says 11.55am.  He also knows about special relativity. In his inertial frame he is at rest.  It is Alice who is moving.  Alice's clock should run slow.  It should show a time of about 11.50am.  But Bob looks at Alice's clock and it reads noon.

Why is there not a contradiction here?

Comment: If both ships accelerate, the frames are not inertial. If the accelerations are the same they will read the same time.

Comment: Are you asking [how time dilation can be symmetric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/383248/how-can-time-dilation-be-symmetric)?

Comment: The title kinda gives it away: Since Galilean relativity is incompatible with Lorentzian relativity, the use of Galilean relativity concepts in SR is likely to go haywire. But the essence of your problem here is that you have assumed and asserted an non-symmetric time dilation, yet you gave us a scenario that naïvely reads as symmetric. We do not have telepathy to know what causes a lack of symmetry in your problem, if it even is lacking symmetry at all. You need to be much more clear on what is what.

Comment: ^ I think what naturallyinconsistent is saying is, you can't just make up the times on the two clocks without justification, and then be like: how come they aren't they the same, what's going on???

Comment: "The clocks of the spaceships are synchronised."  Synchronised in what frame?

Comment: It's not just that the stationary observer sees the moving clock run slower, there's also relativity of simultaneity. For the moving observer (from whichever frame you like), the orientations of space and time *within spacetime* change - in the direction they are moving, what would otherwise happen in the future becomes the present, and this effect grows linearly more pronounced the further ahead of the spaceship you are; similarly, in the other direction, events that are otherwise the past become the present. This affects the synchronization, and the observed tick rate of remote moving cocks.

Answer (score 3):

The elapsed property time over a worldline is:

$$ \Delta\tau = \int_W\frac{dt}{\gamma(t)} $$

where gamma is computed in the initial rest frame.

Since the two $W$ are related by reflection, they will measure the same $\Delta \tau$ at the return point.

They will each see the other clock running slower than their own, though.

Comment: "They will each see the other clock running slower than their own, though."     But if they can physically see their own clock and the other clock, how can that be true?

Comment: So? When you pass opposing traffic on a divided highway, each sees the other further to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Your question includes an incorrect assumption. If Alice and Bob start in the same place with synchronised clocks, and return to the same place having undergone symmetric journeys in opposite directions, then when they return their clocks will show the same reading.

Comment: Thank you.  JEB gives the same answer.  But he adds "They will each see the other clock running slower than their own, though."    And I countered  "But if they can physically see their own clock and the other clock, how can that be true?"

Answer (score 0):

As JEB said, you misanalyzed the problem: both clocks will read noon at the end. But more fundamentally, I don't see how this experiment is related to Galilean relativity in the first place.

Galilean relativity (as illustrated by [Galileo's ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_ship)) says that you can't do any experiment in a closed lab that will determine its velocity relative to, say, the fixed stars. (You can't peek at the stars because the lab is closed.)

If you want to treat your two spaceships as two labs, the principle doesn't apply for two reasons: first, it only applies to velocity, not acceleration, and second, Alice and Bob can't look at each other's clocks because the labs are closed.

If you want to set the whole experiment with both ships in a single huge lab, then I don't see how the experiment relates to the motion of the lab.