# Observer problem in Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

Which clock or observer conclude that time dilation has occurred? Is it the stationary clock/observer or the moving one?
(Please bear in mind that each observer/clock independently concludes that one second has lasped according to their lightclock)

[image]

[image]
The stationary observer concludes that Event A and B occured simultaneously. The moving observer concludes that Event B occured first. Who then concludes that Simultaneity is Relative?

Comment: It is still (as of v2) unclear what you are asking.  However each observer concludes that the other observer's clock is running slowly, and there are probably *thousands* of other physics SE questions on this subject.

Comment: Thank you for your response which I respectfully quote "...However each observer concludes that the other observer's clock is running slowly...". What you have just kindly stated is itself a conclusion. My question is therefore: which observer concludes that ''each observer concludes that the other observer's clock is running slowly''?

Comment: They both do. Each observer makes a conclusion about the other one. The whole point of special relativity is that there is no "objective" reference frame, one can only make claims about someone else's reference frame with respect to their own.

Comment: Well, if they communicate with each other (or can make deductions based on special relativity) then both of them do, obviously.

Comment: I'm tempted to think that you'll soon edit your post to ask *"which observer concludes that (uniform) motion is relative?"*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox

Answer (score 1):

> My question is therefore: which observer concludes that ''each
>   observer concludes that the other observer's clock is running
>   slowly''?

Alice observes that Bob's light clock runs slower than hers and Bob observes that Alice's light clock runs slower than his.

Alice will explain to Bob that the fact that Bob observes her clock to run slow is because Bob's clocks are not synchronized.

Bob will explain to Alice that the fact that Alice observes his clock to run slow is because Alice's clocks are not synchronized.

That relatively moving observers don't agree on whether two events are simultaneous is known as the [relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity).

See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/111089/9887) for a spacetime diagram complete with arguing observers.